# SharePoint 2010 error not found in logs, how to configure logging?

Tags: sharepoint, logging, sharepoint-2010

We have a SharePoint 2010 feature that works fine on my development machine, but won't activate on the staging system. It's SiteCollection scoped, the containing solution was successfully deployed on one WebApplication.

When we try to activate the feature, **we get an error message with a Correlation ID. But we can't find this ID or the name of the feature in the SharePoint Logs nor in the Windows Event Log.**

Maybe logging wasn't configured right or there is an error with ULS on the machine, but we haven't changed the SharePoint Logging options from the state they were after installation. Where can I find exception / error messages that happen in ULS? How must Logging be configured to allow the failed feature activation to be logged?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under SharePoint 2010, go to Central Administration. There is a Monitoring link. Click there and under reporting is a Configure Diagnostic logging link. If you set the Least Critical event to Trace and Least Critical Event items to verbose, you should get more information in the SharePoint log files. Make sure you switch back though after diagnosing because the process is chatty and can result in extra IO and large files.

Out of the box, I don't believe logging is set. You can also verify the location of the log files to make sure they are not on setup elsewhere on this page.

More information at [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748619(v=office.14).aspx)

Comment: We set both drop-down boxes to verbose. The log file got large soon, but again we couldn't find the Correlation ID in it.

Answer (score 3):

Download the ULS Viewer tool from here: [link text](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ULSViewer) and filter by the correlation ID.

Comment: I found the log entry now (not with ULS Viewer) by checking all log files on all frontend servers. Does ULS Viewer somehow allow to search on all frontend servers? I would be happy to accept your answer ...

Comment: @Hinek It doesn't search all front end servers.  You have to run it on the SharePoint machine for it to get the logs.  I've been trying to find a way to monitor a farm with multiple front ends and have yet to get this to work in that scenario.  How did you figure your issue out? Just turn up the logging and search through each machine's logs for the correlation id?

Comment: @MikeG yep, I turned up the logging and searched each machine's logs with `findstr /s /i` for the correlation id.

Comment: Link in this answer is now dead due to Microsoft discontinuing the Archive Gallery. See my answer for revised links. I didn't edit this post as there are two completely different alternatives, one is a non-Microsoft source.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post, but if soone gets the same problem, please try the following:

1. Check who is your farm account user (the user under which SharePoint Timer Service is running).
2. Add this user to local administrators
3. Restart Timer Service.

Please mark this as answer if my solution works for you.

Comment: Be sure to review your farm permissions model before making permissions changes. Best practice is to keep setup and admin separate to reduce attack surface, which means an SPSetup account that is local admin and an SPFarm account that is not. The optimal solution is to ensure that an appropriate account has sufficient permissions for trace logging but not more than is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can always get information from the logs from all servers in the farm using the Merge-SPLogFile cmdlet. The example below filters on a correlation ID, but there are more filter options (tip: Get-Help Merge-SPLogFile -Full).

```
$corrID="some correlation id"
Merge-SPLogFile -Path "path to output file" -Correlation $corrID
```

Answer (score 0):

It is worth emphasizing that the OP's substantive question,

> Where can I find exception / error messages that happen in ULS?

is answered by the OP himself in a comment to @noebierzo,

> I found the log entry ... by checking all log files on all front-end
>   servers.

So be aware if you have a multi-server farm; look at all servers in the farm when checking or searching for errors and trace log messages.

Fortunately Microsoft recently released an updated ULS Viewer v16.0.3129.1000 that provides basic multi-server aggregation of the trace logs. Bill Baer, Senior Technical Product Manager for SharePoint at Microsoft has a [nice blog post on the new version](http://blogs.technet.com/b/wbaer/archive/2014/08/27/uls-viewer-and-sharepoint-2010.aspx) which outlines this feature.

The new version of ULS Viewer is [available from the Microsoft Download Center](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=44020). Note that this version of ULS Viewer requires at least .NET 4.0 which your SharePoint 2010 farm may or may not have installed. Bill [blogs about this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/wbaer/archive/2014/08/27/uls-viewer-and-sharepoint-2010.aspx) but doesn't comment on the impact of installing .NET 4.0 on your SharePoint 2010 farm.

If you want the old version of ULS Viewer v2.0.3530.27850 that only requires .NET 2.0 you can no longer count on Microsoft as they took down the Archive Gallery where it used to live. Fortunately a few people have posted it online, include [Benjamin Athawes on his blog](http://www.benjaminathawes.com/2014/05/26/ulsviewer-exe-download/).

Given the .NET version dependency, and the fact that SharePoint 2010 is still a supported product, Microsoft really should keep an official link around for this prior version ULS Viewer. Suggest you ask Bill about this on his blog. Perhaps SharePoint 2010 SP2 is fully supported side-by-side with .NET 4.0, it would be good to know.