# SharePoint 2010: Errors not showing up in diagnostic log

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am having an issue with the error logging in our development SharePoint 2010 box. This is a new install. When working on an application page, I had an error and went to the logs. Pretty much every other thing in the world is in the logs except for my error(s). I looked for the correlation ID and time and nada.

I've followed tutorials on how to configure the diagnostic logging. This is similar to another StackOverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140059/sharepoint-2010-error-not-found-in-logs-how-to-configure-logging), however the solution isn't working for me and I'm trying ti revive the thread. We have a stanging machine that I was working on until the dev machine was up and the logging worked fine there. I used that as an example and set the SharePoint Foundation and SharePoint Server categories to Error and Medium (I've even set them both to Verbose) with no result.

Anyone else have an issue with this?

Comment: try using sharepoint logviewer [link](http://sharepointlogviewer.codeplex.com). May be it's just a tired eyes problem. 'cos in a fresh install, possibility to find modified logging configuration is too low.

Comment: I've used that one plus the original ULS Viewer. No luck. :-)

Comment: Then, I would log my own exception, write to response for example. Of course I assume it's not a global problem though. if it is, then you should check the core problem.

Comment: I had thought of doing that. Easily enough done. But if it works on one system (installed using the same installation scripts) and not another, it has to be a setting somewhere. Since this is going to be the development box, being forced to put in logging statements in every single code block that could fail sorta sucks.

I've set the permissions levels. I checked to see that the service account has read/write access to that folder. I'm trying to think of what else I could even check.

Comment: Let me explain the steps I would do: 1.Recreate an application page just a button to create an exception and examine the status for logging. I bet it will log. [Then you should Examine the exception your original application page produces and throw it in this new app page! Then if it is not logged, you will be sure that it's the configuration of levels to log your's is wrong.] if not: Create a new web application and a site collection for that and use the application page created in 1st! examine the log! Still no logging. 3. Create another user and test with it to see if it is a user problem.

Comment: I did 1 and 3 but no dice. Seriously! I can't believe it myself. However, in the process, I did activate the Developer Dashboard. I saw the error in the dashboard. So it's being seen somewhere but still not being put into the log. This is getting weirder.

Comment: Please create a dummy web part to create an exception(Not via application page). Then check if it's logged. I assume your log directory may be configured to store logs in some other place then the "LOGS" folder. This is the only possible explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem. Someone told me to make sure the SP webapplication AppPool account is part of the "Performance Log Users" group. After much back-and-forth, I checked the Performance Log Users group and it was EMPTY! I put in my AppPool service account and farm account into that group and also I had to assign the "Log on as a batch job" user right to the Performance Log Users group. It's been logging ever since. :-)